# Can gstreamer's appsink element return original rtp timestamps?

Tags: video, gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer to pull an rtsp stream from an IP camera. Currently, I am using appsink to get the frame data out of the stream but I also need the original RTP timestamp associated with each frame. Is it possible to get the rtp timestamp? In the example I am using the GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP macro to get a timestamp but I do not think its the original rtp timestamp.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/app.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  auto pipeline = gst_parse_launch(
      "rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.0.0.171:554/h264/video.sdp name=rtspsrc latency=100 ! queue !     rtpbin buffer-mode=none ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! appsink name=appsink",
      nullptr);

  auto rtspsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name((GstBin*)pipeline, "rtspsrc");
  if(rtspsrc) {
      g_object_set(rtspsrc, "user-id", "user", nullptr);
      g_object_set(rtspsrc, "user-pw", "password", nullptr);
  }

  auto appsink = (GstAppSink*)gst_bin_get_by_name((GstBin*)pipeline, "appsink");

  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  while(true)
  {
      auto sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);

      if(sample)
      {
          auto buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);

          GstClockTime timestamp = GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP(buffer);

          if(buffer)
          {
              GstMapInfo info;
              gst_buffer_map(buffer, &info, GST_MAP_READ);
              printf("{%lu, %p, %ld}\n",timestamp,info.data,info.size);
          }
      }
      printf(".");
      fflush(stdout);
  }

  auto bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
  auto msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR     | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

  if (msg != NULL)
      gst_message_unref(msg);

  gst_object_unref(bus);

  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  gst_object_unref(pipeline);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am also using a similar pipeline and trying to read RTP timestamps. Any progress on this matter? Also are you sure that what you are reading is not RTP ts, and how did you understand that?